# Fade In and out on scroll with opacity value setting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
          var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
          var height = jQuery(window).height();
          jQuery('.background_top_dissolvenza').css({
             'opacity': ((height - scrollTop) / height)
          });
     });
  });
```

I would like to stop the opacity value at 0.5 while now it reaches 0 and even further, with negative values ​​as I scroll.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use `Math.max()`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
          var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
          var height = jQuery(window).height();
          jQuery('.background_top_dissolvenza').css({
              'opacity': Math.max((height - scrollTop) / height, 0.5)
          });
     });
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vn0tb80f/)